# Is it possible to encrypt passwords while connecting to SQL Server 2012 through php?

Tags: php, sql-server, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt the password while connecting to SQL Server 2012. I know there are 2 ways to do it :

```
$serverName = "serverName"; 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DbName", 
                         "UID"=>"UserName", 
                         "PWD"=>"Password", 
                         "Encrypt"=>true, 
                         "TrustServerCertificate"=>false); 
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

and

```
$uid = file_get_contents("C:\AppData\uid.txt");
$pwd = file_get_contents("C:\AppData\pwd.txt");
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,
                         "PWD"=>$pwd,
                         "Database"=>"AdventureWorks");
```

but i would like to know if it is possible to encrypt it without mentioning the original password in the connection string.

I tried using the following code, but I get an error saying login has failed.

```
$serverName = "serverName"; 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DbName", 
                         "UID"=>"UserName", 
                         "PWD"=>"7110eda4d09e062aa5e4a390b0a572ac0d2c0220"); //Encrypted Password
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to be possible, in addition, it's not really usefull. Why would you encrypt it in your code, unfortunately (unless you're using direct socket), the mysql (or mssql, or pgsql, etc) password will always be visible in your code.

But since no one will ever be able to see your code (unless your website got hacked), it's not really a problem. But for the moment I would not quality that as an issue, but maybe you've good reason to to that.

Comment: I just want to make sure that even if someone gets access to the config file, they won't be able to read the password. And also, this is a requirement out internal IT audit had asked for. :)

Comment: Well, if someone have an access to the config file, it probably mean access to your full website (from LFI, XXE, ...), meaning that you're screwed, no matter if your password is crypted or not. Maybe explain to your IT team that their request is pointless

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about someone seeing your config file, you can use Environment variables to store your password, in Linux there's bashrc, I am sure you can set enviroment vars in Windows too, once you have set it, You can call the environment variable using PHP like this `$_ENV["MY_DB_PW"]`. This is still accessible to the person who uses your system in many ways but atleast they won't see the plain password in the config file ;) Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I tried accessing through '$_ENV['']' but doesn't work :) It yet gives an error saying login failed.

Comment: did you check if $_ENV["MY_DB_PW"] returns any value at all ?

Comment: It's not, tried using getenv(' ') and $_SERVER[''], they don't return a value too.. I've checked the case too and it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into something similar in the past and I think the solution is a hardware security module (HSM) to store your password off your server.

You can read about them here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module

Comment: Thanks! Shall look into it :) Would prefer if it was something in php though :)